# Use only one dbcontext for two projects

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-6, dbcontext

I'm working on an app with 3 projects. A class library, a web project and a mobile project. I'm working with ef code first migrations, identity mvc and localdb. I want to share the context between the web project and mobile project, but I don't know why I'm generating two contexts, so when I change between projects I have different data

This is the structure:

- Model: I got here my IdentityConfig, the context, the migrations folder and all the models for my app.
- CMS: My web project, got here controllers, viewmodels and views. I have the Startup.cs and Startup.Auth.cs as well
- Mobile: Here I got only controllers, viewmodels and views.

Both CMS and Mobile have a reference to the Model project.

But then I get this:

[image]

EDIT:

That's how my DbContext looks like

```
public class PackagingHouseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public PackagingHouseContext()
        : base("PackagingHouseContext", false)
    {
    }

    public static PackagingHouseContext Create()
    {
        return new PackagingHouseContext();
    }

    public DbSet<Client> Clients { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Contact> Contacts { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Machine> Machines { get; set; }
    public DbSet<Film> Films { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<PluralizingTableNameConvention>();
    }

}
```

Comment: you mobile project will read/write data on mobile device(maybe sqlite) or on a web server

Comment: What does your `DbContext` file look like?

Comment: @chenZ The mobile project will read/write data from the same database as the web project, in a web server

Comment: @lbrahim I just updated my post with the dbcontext

Comment: @Tomás Escamez so you not need share dbcontext,you should write some restful api in web project,and use these api in mobile.the api read/write data use dbcontext

Comment: @chenZ Yes, I'm thinking about create a new project, some kind of a service layer and then the web and the mobile will have a reference to that service project. Anyway, I want to know why this happened. It's working properly with a Sql database

Comment: @Tomás Escamez i think there are some point,in a ntire app,mobile is just a view layer,logic and data on server,you can change your logic without users update mobile app,secure may another point,write db from mobile may not safe;app's size may another point